# Can i write both alpine.js and jquery in same project, will it cause any document behaviours?

Tags: jquery, alpine.js

for ex in alipine, component names like below, will it confuse jQuery, please advise with more use cases. thanks.

```
window.profileForm = function () {
    return {}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It shouldn't do unless you override `$` or `jQuery` globals in code.

By default Alpine will only add the `Alpine` global.

Alpine also runs the code you provide it (in directives for example) in a component-scoped environment in order to provide the necessary reactive component state to it.

Comment: Thanks @Hugo, implemented those logics, which works great with #Alpine along with #jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

I do it all the time, this is what my app.js with Vite looks like:

```
import jQuery from 'jquery';

import Alpine from 'alpinejs'; 

window.Alpine = Alpine;
 

Alpine.start();

window.jQuery = jQuery;
//SEE https://github.com/alpinejs/alpine/pull/2063
// This change would allow to enable compatibility with jQuery event system
document.addEventListener('alpine:init', () => {
  Alpine.setListenerManipulators(
    (target, event, handler, options, modifiers) => { jQuery(target).on(event, handler) },
    (target, event, handler, options) => { jQuery(target).off(event, handler) }
  )
})
/* EXAMPLE: 
    <span @click="val='new'" x-text="val"></span>
    <button onclick="$('span').trigger('click')">Update</button>
*/
```

Comment: How it's even works if setListenerManipulators is do not exists in AlpineJS repository?

Comment: @KorbenDallas I don't understand. Does it not exist anymore? It definitely used to and worked. Please see: https://github.com/alpinejs/alpine/pull/2063

Comment: this pull request was not merged, though it doesn't work

Comment: @KorbenDallas Well my alpineJS and Jquery in my main application work magically together. And I put that code. It doesn't even through errors. I never bothered to read and know the AlpineJS library as well as you do I only use it for Livewire with Laravel.